# edit .tgz file in windows

Tags: windows, software-rec

I'm trying to add some driver files to my smoothwall install (slipstream style)

I am trying to do this from my win7 box (as i don't have any lunix boxes available nor would i want to use them)

I know i can open these files with winzip or winrar or 7zip but i cant seem to edit with any of the usuall suspect and all my google searches thus far are just for instruction on how to view/open files in win not to edit.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about WinZIP, but Winrar and 7zip can definitelly create tgz (tar+gzip) archives.

Comment: WinRAR doesn't allow you to edit those. But 7-Zip works well to edit those